# Adding images to video with help of this MediaCodec Api

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-mediacodec, android-textureview, android-video-record

I am trying to add waterMark to the video by using this library but i couldn't the get the desired result as shown in the library https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android . can anyone point out or help me how to solve it thanks
what i tried

```
 mp4Composer = new Mp4Composer(videoItem.getPath(), videoPath)
            // .rotation(Rotation.ROTATION_270)
            .size(720, 720)
            .fillMode(FillMode.PRESERVE_ASPECT_FIT)
            .filter(new GlWatermarkFilter(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher_background), GlWatermarkFilter.Position.LEFT_BOTTOM))
            .mute(muteCheckBox.isChecked())
            .flipHorizontal(flipHorizontalCheckBox.isChecked())
            .flipVertical(flipVerticalCheckBox.isChecked())
            .listener(new Mp4Composer.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(double progress) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onProgress = " + progress);
                    runOnUiThread(() -> progressBar.setProgress((int) (progress * 100)));
                }
```

I tried adding this line:
filter(new GlWatermarkFilter(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher_background), GlWatermarkFilter.Position.LEFT_BOTTOM))

Comment: If you have solved this can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61998318/draw-bitmap-in-specified-xy-positions-in-the-canvas